# data of foreign keys are not saving in django admin nested inlines

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin, inlines, django-nested-admin

I'm trying to build a list of replicable fields where the order can be interchanged.
To do so I've built three different models `Multicap Multitext Multimg` which are Inlines of the model `Multis` which is an Inline of the model `Delta`.

I'm using [django-nested-admin](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html) and everything works fine on the admin page, I can add new objects and change their order.

The problem I have is that when I populate the fields, save the model and then check its content, **all the data of the text fields are turned into zeros 0**.

[image]

instead, when I try to save the image I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'field'`

**models.py**

```
class Multis(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    delta = models.ForeignKey('Delta', related_name="delta", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Multicap(models.Model):
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    multic = models.ForeignKey('Multis', related_name="multicap", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('caption',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.caption)


class Multimg(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", verbose_name='Image', null=True, blank=True,)
    multim = models.ForeignKey('Multis', related_name="multimg", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('img',)

    @property
    def img_url(self):
      if self.img and hasattr(self.img, 'url'):
        return self.img.url

    def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
        title = instance.post.title
        slug = slugify(title)
        return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('delta-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Multitext(models.Model):
    text = tinymce_models.HTMLField(null=True, blank=True)
    multit = models.ForeignKey('Multis', related_name="multitext", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('text',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)

class Delta(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=50, null="true")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('heading',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.heading)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('delta-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
import nested_admin
from nested_admin import SortableHiddenMixin, NestedTabularInline, NestedModelAdmin, NestedStackedInline
from .models import Delta, Multimg, Multitext, Multicap, Multis


class MimgAdmin(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Multimg
    sortable_field_name = "img"
    extra = 0

class MtxtAdmin(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Multitext
    sortable_field_name = "text"
    extra = 0

class McapAdmin(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Multicap
    sortable_field_name = "caption"
    extra = 0

class MAdmin(nested_admin.SortableHiddenMixin, nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Multis
    sortable_field_name = "name"
    extra = 0
    inlines = [ McapAdmin, MtxtAdmin, MimgAdmin ]


@admin.register(Delta)
class DeltaAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    sortable_field_name = "delta"
    inlines = [ MAdmin ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was a stupid error related to `sortable_field_name`

This field needs to be related to a field in the model which has to be formulated this way:

models.py

```
position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position", null=True)
```

admin.py

```
sortable_field_name = 'position'
```

This forms a position field that has a basic value of 0. Doing the way I was doing so this value was being substituted for the field I wanted to fill in.

Hope this can help someone occuring in the same error